# Find bugs/enhancements closed in Java 9?

Tags: java, issue-tracking, java-9

I know the OpenJDK has a [JIRA](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira) issue-tracking system, [*JDK Bug System*](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/secure/Dashboard.jspa).

Is there some way to use that tool, or some other source, to get a list of all the bug/enhancement/change tickets that are:

- Related to a specific area such as the `java.time` package, ***and***
- Closed/resolved in a specific version of Java such as Java 9?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the filter facility in the same BugJira link.

example: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8167257?jql=project%20in%20(JDK)%20AND%20component%20in%20(core-libs)%20AND%20Subcomponent%20in%20(java.time)

This one filters on `Component:core-libs and Subcomponent : java.time`.

You can also filter it by closed/open and other status.